# Whats new in Firefox 5?

Tags: 11.04, firefox

I tried the support sites in Mozilla and couldn't find any info about whats new in Firefox 5, so I thought I would see if you guys could point me in the right direction. My system was upgraded to fx5 last night (6/21) and I have been able to find any info on it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The release notes are available here (too many to list here):

- http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/5.0/releasenotes/

And here's the [complete list](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/5.0/releasenotes/buglist.html) of bugs fixed.

Comment: "Holy Crud" that's a long list! Lets hope the "add-ons" developers get all the extensions working that aren't compatible with fx5!

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 5 changes in simple words

Even though the GUI has not been changed, Firefox 5 features:

```
Better standards support for HTML 5, CSS3, MathML, XHR and SMIL
Better visibility for the Do-Not-Track header preference
Stability and security improvements
WebGL security has been tightened up.
Better tuned HTTP idle connection logic
Improved canvas, JavaScript, memory, and networking performance
Improved spell checking for some locales
Improved desktop environment integration for Linux users
WebGL content can no longer load cross-domain textures
Background tabs have setTimeout and setInterval clamped to 1000ms to improve performance
```

Via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_5)